# How to achieve this caching with spring annotation based ehcache

Tags: spring, caching

We want to use `Spring annotation` based ehcache in our application.
We are the `RESTFul` service providers for the front end mobile apps.

The **input** which we are getting from the mobile app is in delimited format like this:

> COUNTRY1 :: STATE1, STATE2, STATE3 ; COUNTRY2:: STATE4, STATE5, STATE6.

Now in our response we need to send all the states information for each of the country in the JSON format. so it will come sth like this

```
{
 country1 : [
  state1 : [{},{},{}]
],
country2 : [
]
}
```

We do have some service method like

```
getSateInformation(String country, String state)
```

This is an existing method signature which internally talks to DAO and both country and state are passed to the query to get the required state level information.
Till now they were passing the values like this

```
country --> COUNTRY1, COUNTRY2
state ---> state1, state2, state3
```

In the query both of them are passed into the IN clause so all the values are returned in 1 shot.

Now the query is when we want to build cache layer we want to cache the state level information only once, so we cannot pass country and state as comma separated because we will have multiple entries in cache which is not a good design.

so we thought of the following design

1. iterate through the input string which we are getting from the client.
2. For each country and state make a service call which will fetch the data from db and cache it.

By doing the above approach we will cache the **country + state** level information only once in memory and can serve all requests from cache. But the issue is that for the first time request it will take lot of time because we will have to make multiple DB calls for each country and state combination.

So we were thinking if we can cache the values during the deployment time itself for each country and state combination then it will help.

**So just want to check on two aspects**

1. is there any better way of doing it or any better design approach to cache it.
2. How we can cache the values even before the first request hits our service.
3. Can we use some cron job for doing this which we can configure in spring?